# Erro '15.0' is not a valid floating point value ao salvar .xls

Tags: delphi, microsoft-excel

Ao tentar salvar um arquivo .xls estou tendo a seguinte erro:

> '15.0' is not a valid floating point value

Estou tentando salvar assim:

```
var
HCalc : THojaCalc;
vArquivo : String;

vArquivo := 'C:/MinhaPasta/Arquivo.xls'; //dentro do arquivo.xls não tem nenhum valor
HCalc := THojaCalc.create(vArquivo, False);
HCalc.ActivateSheetByIndex(1);
HCalc.CellText[3,2] := 'teste';
HCalc.SaveDocAs(vArquivo,True); //aqui da o erro
HCalc.Free;
```

Comment: O caminho do arquivo é com a barra "para direita" mesmo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que o `THojaCalc` ao salvar, tenta pegar a versão da Aplicativo `OleObject`, que no seu caso é o Excel, e jogar essa versão para um `Extended`, e a versão do seu Excel é a '15.0'.
Não tem como você jogar um '15.0' para um `Float`, voce vai precisa mudar esse cara para '15,0'.

Fiz uma alteração no componente, e vou sugerir o ajuste para os colaboradores.

Para você poder seguir, troque a linha 890 por este código:

```
exVersion := StrToFloat(StringReplace(m_vPrograma.Application.Version, '.', ',', [rfReplaceAll]), m_AmericanFormat);
```

Obs.: Lembrando que tratar a versão de um app como `Float` não é seguro.

Comment: Acho que o projeto foi descontinuado, mas segue o link do Fork: https://github.com/charoleizer/Delphi-SpreadSheets

Answer (score 1):

Faça uma alteração no seu código logo abaixo do `CellText`.

Use também a barra da esquerda `\` no caminho do arquivo!

```
var
HCalc : THojaCalc;
vArquivo : String;

vArquivo := 'C:\MinhaPasta\Arquivo.xls'; //dentro do arquivo.xls não tem nenhum valor
HCalc := THojaCalc.create(vArquivo, False);
HCalc.ActivateSheetByIndex(1);
HCalc.CellText[3,2] := 'teste';
HCalc.AddNewSheet('AbaTeste'); //Aqui
HCalc.SaveDocAs(vArquivo,True); //aqui da o erro
HCalc.Free;
```